# compute differences between current values and previous values using diff

Tags: r, diff

How can I use the diff function to compute differences between current values and previous values *instead of the difference between the next value and the current value*.

Comment: Do you mean `c(x[1], diff(x))` ?

Comment: Yes, that works! Deceptively simple, thanks so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is @Andrie's solution wrapped in a function:

```
x = c(1,4,5,8)
diff( x )
[1] 3 1 3

newDiff <- function( a )
{
  x <- a[1]
  x <- c( x, diff( a ) )
  return( x )
} 

newDiff( x )
[1] 1 3 1 3
```